# Illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql

Firstly I should state that my database is no longer designed in the following way.
This is purely to allow the archives from before to show.

```
SELECT t.user, t.team, t.home_games_played, t.home_wins, t.home_draws, t.home_losses, t.home_points, t.home_goals_for, t.home_goals_against, 
                  t.away_games_played, t.away_wins, t.away_draws, t.away_losses, t.away_points, t.away_goals_for, t.away_goals_against, t.vacant, te.team as teamname, 
                  te.colour
                  FROM tbl_foot_leaguetables t
                  INNER JOIN tbl_foot_teams te ON t.team = te.team
                  WHERE league = '44'
                  ORDER BY t.home_points + t.away_points DESC,(t.home_goals_for + t.away_goals_for) - (t.home_goals_against + t.away_goals_against) DESC, 
                  t.home_goals_for + t.away_goals_for DESC, t.user
```

This query throws up the following error

> Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

It is the following part of the query that is to blame

```
INNER JOIN tbl_foot_teams te ON t.team = te.team
```

What it is trying to do is join two words that are identical together.

For example, 'Portugal' to 'Portugal'.

This was bad design but I have to do it to get what I want.

Now my database connects ID's etc.

Any ideas how to fix this? Or find a work around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collation is wrong. If you look in phpMyAdmin (I assume that you have that) you can see a collation for each varchar() or other string-based storage format.

This is related to character encoding. MySQL will store the data depending on that charset, and if the first string has a different encoding than the other string (different collations) it can't do a binary compare. This would be a MAJOR performance hit on your query which is why it simply refuses.

I'd suggest setting all collation values to the same (`latin1_general_ci` is popular, or maybe even `utf8_general_ci` which is what everyone should use). Changing collations usually won't affect the data, only the way it's stored. You're always safe if you switch everything to UTF-8 (`utf8_general_ci`)

Comment: Incredible, something I need to learn more about! I've changed latin1_swedish_ci to general to make the other. That seems to have fixed it. Cheers bud.

Comment: i think utf8_unicode_ci is better for international.
sorts international characters properly i believe

Answer (score 0):

Your tables `tbl_foot_leaguetables` and `tbl_foot_teams` have different collations, so their string values cannot be compared directly. You have to either change one table's collation or use another check.

Comment: Never come across this before! By changing the collation, will that change what's in the field and lose data?

Comment: No, but you can also use `COLLATE latin1_general_ci` to explicitly set a collation for the column in the expression: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collate.html